# Assume local instead of Unspecified DateTime from SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, datetime, sqlclient

Because the SQL Server datatype `datetime` does not keep any timezone information, the SqlClient in .NET is instantiating all `DateTime` objects with `Kind` set to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. That is of cause the right thing to do - theoretically. BUT almost every application I have worked on has stored datetime assuming it to be local, and lived happy for long time.

But when globalization demands arise, there is some trouble with this assumption / convention. For instance JSON serialization is not to be trusted!

So the question: is it possible to do something either on the database, or on the web server, to enforce that datetime read from database (via `SqlClient.DataReader.GetDateTime`) is assumed `DateTimeKind.Local`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to enforce that a `DateTime` pulled from the reader is automatically assumed to be a local time, but it's easy enough to change immediately afterwards using the [`SpecifyKind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind.aspx) method:

```
var unspecifiedValue = yourReader.GetDateTime(yourColumn);
var localValue = DateTime.SpecifyKind(unspecifiedValue, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

You could also wrap this up in an extension method if you prefer (either hardcoding the `DateTimeKind` as I've done here, passing it in as an argument, or pulling it from config):

```
var localValue = yourReader.GetLocalDateTime(yourColumn);

// ...

public static DateTime GetLocalDateTime(this IDataRecord source, int i)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    return DateTime.SpecifyKind(source.GetDateTime(i), DateTimeKind.Local);
}
```

Comment: Specifying the kind, is what we do all over the place, but I would prefer, to make this 'specification' in a config, or some kind of global converter.
Specifying the kind, in every model property is not very DRY

Comment: @Jesper: Can't be done, as far as I'm aware. You could create an extension method to make everything cleaner (see my edit). You could also read your desired `DateTimeKind` from config and use that in the extension method, if that suits your needs.

Comment: Your line of fixing the problem, is what we do all over, and I agree that your encapsulation is clean, but now every new developer has to remember to do this override/addendum on every future autogenerated EF of CSLA class. Doomed to be forgotten - I think.
Maybe the only way, is to convert all db columns of type datetime, to datetimeoffset..